# When I tap on UITextView at a particular place I want to change the color of that particular line

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

1. I have a textView
2. When I tap on a particular area of the textview I find the line number but I can not get the text of that line
3. I need to get the text of a particular line and change only that text's color in the textview

   ```
    func HandleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("tapped")
        if sender.state == .recognized {
            let location = sender.location(ofTouch: 0, in: TextView)
            print(location)
            if location.y >= 0 && location.y <= TextView.contentSize.height {
           guard let font = TextView.font else {
               return
            }
           let line = Int((location.y - TextView.textContainerInset.top) / font.lineHeight) + 1
           print("Line is \(line)")
           let text=TextView.textContainer
           print(text)


          }
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please show the code you are using so we know what you have tried so far.  If you do that then we have a chance of helping you.

Comment: func HandleTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        print("tapped")
        if sender.state == .recognized {
            let location = sender.location(ofTouch: 0, in: TextView)
            print(location)
            if location.y >= 0 && location.y <= TextView.contentSize.height {
                guard let font = TextView.font else {
                    return
                }
                let line = Int((location.y - TextView.textContainerInset.top) / font.lineHeight) + 1
                print("Line is \(line)")
                
            }
        }
    }

Comment: i am new in iOS development

Comment: Can you edit the question to add that code instead of having it in a comment as that makes it much easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension to UITextView to get the line of text at the current line selected:

```
func getLineString() -> String {
    return (self.text! as NSString).substringWithRange((self.text! as NSString).lineRangeForRange(self.selectedRange))
}
```

Then from there you'll need to change all the text to attributed text and change just the range of your selected line text to your highlight color. Something like:

```
let allText = textView.text
let lineText = textView.getLineString()

let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: allText)

let regularFont = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30.0)! // Make this whatever you need
let highlightFont = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 30.0)! // Make this whatever you need

//  Convert allText to NSString because attrText.addAttribute takes an NSRange.
let allTextRange = (allText as NSString).rangeOfString(allText)
let lineTextRange = (allText as NSString).rangeOfString(lineText)

attrText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: regularFont, range: allTextRange)
attrText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: highlightFont, range: lineTextRange)

textView.attributedText = attrText
```

Comment: i need to change only one line not all the text

Comment: but your code change all the text of the textview and also tell me about textString in this code

Comment: Sorry, textString should have been allText instead. When you debug this verify that the value of the `lineText` variable is just the line you tapped. The `lineTextRange` should give you only the range of your selected line.

Comment: i checked that code it changes all the text in the textview but i wanna change only one particular line. is it possible?

Comment: Try applying a different font formatting to the entire text first and then add the specific font for your highlight line after that. See the updated answer.